# @private - using it or not?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, class-design, encapsulation, private-members

What is the point of using the @private directive in Xcode when you are working alone or with a team that can access all properties, ivars of an app?

Is there any advantage like memory usage, performance, etc? or is this just a stuff for large teams where one part should not be using stuff that can change in the future?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `@private` in the `@interface` of a class declaration ensures that no other class has access to the ivars. This is important for encapsulation. And this is just as important for a single developer as it is for a team of dozens of developers.

Encapsulation ensures you only use the provided API for a class without the need to know how it works internally. Some time down the road you may wish to change the implementation. This should have no effect on any classes already using the class. The aPI won't change, just its implementation.

Remember, ivars should only be accessed within the implementation of the given class. No other class should have access to those ivars. Otherwise your code becomes very fragile and difficult to maintain.

Edit: With modern Objective-C you shouldn't even have any ivars in the .h file anymore. Move them to the @implementation line where they are guaranteed to be private and no one using the .h file even knows what ivars you have.

Comment: what? Do you mean all my pretty ivars from .h have to go to .m? ಠ_ಠ This is another thing I never understood completely. Why some programmers declare ivars and properties with the same name? As far as I always thought, once you declare a property, you don't need an ivar with the same name... right?

Comment: I didn't say you have to move the ivars from the .h to the .m. I said you should because it further promotes encapsulation. With modern Objective-C you can declare a property with `@property` and you are done. Prior to this it was required to use `@property`, `@synthesize`, and declare an ivar. So anytime you see this, it is code written using an older compiler or written by people that haven't started using the new features of the latest compiler.

Comment: ok, thanks, but I am not talking about "@synthesize", I am talking about people who declare ivars on .h, on the "@interface" part, then declare the property with the same name also in .h, then "@synthesize" them in .m using something like "@synthesize variable = _variable;"

Comment: That's what I was talking about. This used to be required before the modern Objective-C compiler started letting us just use `@property` and nothing else.

Comment: where I can read about these changes and how to modernize my code? thanks again.

Comment: Session 405 from WWDC 2012 is a great place to learn about these changes and other. Also look at the Objective-C docs in Xcode.